# Package updated to angular 5 latest version but npm not updated in visual studio 2017 using angular template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, angular5

I have updated the angular 4 to angular 5 in visual studio 2017 template.

I followed the instruction from the link 
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/

npm install -g npm-check-updates

ncu -u

The package.json file got updated but the npm are not updated and some of the npm package are not instralled.

Here is the screen shots
[image: screen shots]

From the image the right side package is updated to 5.5.1 but the npm dependency are still pointing to the older version.

How can solve this issue.

Comment: remove the node modules folder and do a `npm install` again

Answer (score 6):

I had the very same problem and taking the following steps resolves it:

1. Delete ***npm-shrinkwrap.json*** file (expand package.json file to see it)
2. Delete the ***node_modules*** folder in your project folder
3. Re-install npm:

   ```
   npm install -g npm-check-updates
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well. It looks like you're using the Angular template from VS 2017. There is a file called npm-shrinkwrap.json, that is included that locks the versioning. Delete that file and then try restoring the packages. If you don't see, try expanding the package.json in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to changes not effect in `package-lock.json/npm-shrinkwrap.json` update the npm version, now try to update the `npm install {packagename}` this will reflect in both files. and not a recommended way to manually change versions in `package.json`.