# Can not find module '@angular/common/http' in Angular 5, ASP.Net Core 2.0 & Webpack

Tags: webpack, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0

I have made an app using ASP .NET core 2.0, angular 5.2.9 and Webpack in Visual Studio 2017 Community. But when trying to import HttpClientModule from '@angular/common/http', the error- "Can not find module '@angular/common/http' '" appeared in intellisence. What to do?

Actually importing from '@angular/http' is not raising any error which was before Angular 4.3.0 but after that(current version is 5.2.9) importing from '@angular/common/http' should work. Do I have to do something with webpack?

Below is my package.json:-

```js
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~9.4.7",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0", 
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.10.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "4.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.3",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "5.5.7",
    "style-loader": "0.20.3",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "url-loader": "1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.1.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~9.4.7",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.2",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have `@angular/common` installed?

Comment: Yes, Off course.

Comment: did you install it via npm?

Comment: Yes, I am providing package.json of my app

Comment: you have quite a few things in dependencies which are dev dependencies only

Comment: In package.json file you can see  "@angular/common". i.e.  @angular/common is installed successfully. So I can expect that HttpClient can be imported from @angular/common/http.

Comment: but for example, `"@angular/cli": "1.7.3", "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0", "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0", "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6", "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2", "@types/node": "~9.4.7",` plus others should not be in the dependencies, only dev dependencies

Comment: Does the folder exist on disk e.g. /node_modules/@angular/common/http?

Comment: No, there is no folder named "http" inside common. But I have updated the angular packages by npm/powershell command prompt.

Comment: Thanks, @Simply Gred. I have created new app using angular CLI and then copied the node_modules folder from there(which contained the http folder inside common folder) to my app. But could not understand that why those folder did not copied into node_modules of my app instead of updating the angular packages using command prompt!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have created new app using angular CLI and then copied the node_modules folder from there(which contained the http folder inside common folder) to my app. This solved my problem. But this seems not to be a proper solution to this problem. I believe that there might be more logical way of doing this addressing the proper reason for this issue. So still my waiting for more appropriate answer(nice to have explanation) is not exhausted :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; created an Angular project in Visual Studio 2017, installed the angular CLI and upgraded it to Angular 5.
Going through the tutorial it was failing in the same spot.

Solved it by modifying the package.json file, removed the line:

```
   "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
```

removed the project node_modules folder and then ran npm_install.

This time it installed the Angular common http folder as expected.

I guess it doesn't add the common http module if the original module is still there?

Comment: Actually the angular templates available for ASP .NET core does not have updated Angular packages though it contains version of Angular >4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out that the shrinkwrap file that gets added by vs2017 was preventing it from updating to v5.

Steps to resolve are:

1. Delete npm-shrinkwrap.json file (expand package.json file to see it)
2. Delete the node_modules folder in your project folder
3. Re-install npm:
   npm install -g npm-check-updates

Taken from:

[Package updated to angular 5 latest version but npm not updated in visual studio 2017 using angular template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364436/package-updated-to-angular-5-latest-version-but-npm-not-updated-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Just wait until VS updates references by Package Manager.